# text to column delimiter split at any number

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I split a clustered alphanumeric column at the first instance of a number?

Preferrably simpler [than this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/extracting-numbers-from-alphanumeric-strings-HA001154901.aspx).

[image]

Comment: You are importing from a CSV file, it seems. Maybe you can pre-process the information before loading it into the Excel spreadsheet?

Comment: I was just about to create the formula when I noticed the link you provided. I don't think you can do it much simpler than this!

Comment: It's not from a csv. Thanks for your effort guys, I will see what I can do.

Comment: Short of a Vba solution those giant formulas are the way to go for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve what you want simpler than suggested by MS, do the following:

1. Open your file using **MS Word**, not Excel.
2. Open `Replace` dialog via <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.
3. Set up the options as on the screen (`Use wildcards` MUST be checked!):

[image: Wildcards Replace]

These options (wildcards) mean the following:

- Find what: `([0-9]{1,})` - means any digit 1 or more times. `()` brackets are required for future use - they mark string blocks.
- Replace with: `,\1` - comma and 1st `Find what` block in `()` brackets.

Press `Replace All` - your strings will be converted like this: `NY City 4a` --> `NY City ,4a`

Now save the resulting file as **TEXT** (not Word Document!), change extension to **CSV** and simply open it in Excel. If your default CSV separator is comma - you'll have strings with comma separated into 2 cells. If you have different default separator - replace comma in the above "Replace with:" expression by this character.

Read more about wildcards: [Finding and replacing characters using wildcards](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/general/usingwildcards.htm).

Comment: @nixda Frankly, for me Excel-based solution is much simpler, but if OP insists, so....))))

Comment: Clever. It does get the job done.

Comment: @andrewk Glad to help buddy) If you're happy with the solution proposed - please accept the answer by ticking it, this will mark the question solved. For the details see: [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/210367)

Comment: @PeterL. why not

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at this article from microsoft:  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/extracting-numbers-from-alphanumeric-strings-HA001154901.aspx

Comment: Well, have you noticed the link in the question?

Comment: yes -- sorry!  Skipped over it at first.